# Rust: memory deallocation for String

Tags: memory, memory-management, rust, dealloc

Do I need to deallocate memory manually in this case:

```
let mut s = String::new();
...somecode here...
s = String::new();
```

and is it the best way to erase content of the string?

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what you mean by "erase content of the string"?

Answer (score 1):

In such simple cases, Rust will automatically free memory when it us no longer needed.

If you want to assign a zero-length string to `s`, you can use the [`clear`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.clear) function:

```
s.clear();
```

This preserves the current capacity (and allocation) of the string.  The alternative you cited,

```
s = String::new();
```

does not do this.  Both approaches have their uses, depending on the circumstances.  Sometimes, retaining a large string allocation is wasteful (if the string will never grow to this size again).